# PHP giving Undefined array key warning despite array key existing

Tags: php, arrays

I am reading data from a CSV file with `fgetcsv()` with PHP 8.4. When reading the headers I flip these with `array_flip` to get a header representing an index in a `$headers` array.

```
$csv = fopen($path, "r");

$headers = array_flip(fgetcsv($csv));
print_r($headers);
echo $headers["Tag"];
```

Printing the array proves that this key exists yet when I try and use it I get told that the key does not exist

```
Array
(
    [Tag] => 0
    [x] => 1
    [x] => 2
    [x] => 3
    [x] => 4
    [x] => 5
    [x] => 6
    [x] => 7
    [x] => 8
    [x] => 9
    [x] => 10
    [lowercase] => 11
)
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "Tag" in test_parse.php on line 63
```

I have replaced the variable names with an `x` for confidentiality. These are not relevant to the problem as far I am aware.

My only guess at the problem is that the text encoding from reading the CSV is different to me trying to access it with `$headers["Tag"]`. I have tried encoding/decoding the strings to UTF-8 but I'm not having any luck.

Comment: Please inform the correct PHP version. I've tested a csv (tag,test,test,test,test) with PHP 8.0.21 and everything went ok.

Comment: @Max I'm on PHP 8.1.8

Comment: Try `$headers = array_flip(array_map('trim', fgetcsv($csv)));`.  Also, `var_dump(fgetcsv($csv));` will give the lengths.